# ImageAdapter is not working with String array. Unable to understand error here

Tags: android, adapter

i am creating an image gallery using gridview and image adapter. When I pass static values from project folder to the image adapter it works fine. But when i tried to get the list of image path from database and then populate with same procedure it gives error

This is my image adapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;

GetData findData = new GetData();



public String[] images = findData.getImageList(1);

public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    context = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return images[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(images[position]));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(240,240));
    return imageView;
}
}
```

And this is the function that I am calling to get the String array list of image paths:

```
    public String[] getImageList(Integer schoolId) {
    String[] imageList = new String[500];

    try {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DBuser, DBpassword);


        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select `image_path` FROM `photo_gallery` WHERE `school_id`=" + schoolId);

        //ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

        int i = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            if (rs != null) {
                imageList[i] = rs.getString("image_path");
                i++;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return imageList;
}
```

and this is my error log

```
08-05 12:29:45.458 12782-12782/com.adt.alphadev.itdp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.adt.alphadev.itdp, PID: 12782
                                                                   java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
                                                                       at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                                                                       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                                                                       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                                                                       at com.adt.alphadev.itdp.Hm.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:60)
                                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
                                                                       at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1060)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
                                                                       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:607)
                                                                       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:674)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

What is going on here....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here

```
imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(images[position]));
```

You're trying to convert a string (image path) to an integer and provide that integer to `setImageResource`. That's not possible.

First, because `setImageResource` accepts a drawable id (that should be inside the apk).

Second, I'm expecting that the image path might be on SD, therefore you have to load the images in a different way.

Comment: image is on the localhost server, and i am trying to retrieve the path here.  Path is in String type and i am trying to load it by index position of array. Is there any better way to get the list rather than String array?

Answer (score 0):

**imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(images[position]));**

Here is the problem.
Firstly your **images[position] is null**.Check that array.

Secondly the code should be:

```
imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
```

Comment: Initially i did this only but then android studio asked me to parse it into int value